# Angular2 - reference element state

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms

I have this Component

```
@Component({
    selector: 'registration-form',
    template: `
        <label for="email" class="name">Email</label>
        <input #email id="email" class="input" ngControl="email">
        <tooltip [visible]="if-email-input-above-is-focused"></tooltip>
    `,
    directives: [
        TooltipComponent
    ]
})

export class RegistrationForm {

}
```

and I want to show the tooltip component only if the above input field is focused. The thing is, I don't want to write custom funcions for all input fields but only somehow to reference state of field above.

What is the most intelligent way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `focus` and `blur` events together like:

```
<input id="email" class="input" ngControl="email" (focus)="visible=1" (blur)="visible=0">
<div *ngIf="visible">Tooltip</div>
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/NX0uHTensAVEVbiZzmaa?p=preview)**